# how to extract json body as string using java

Tags: java, json, api, jsoup, jsonresponse

I have a JSON response and i am extracting the body using getbody() command and storing the responses in list. because i am passing multiple JSON at a time so each response i am storing in list as string value. How can i extract that JSON using JAVA?

```
   response = request.post(route.payment());
            body = response.getBody();
            listofBody.add(body.asString());
```

above code is where i get the response and store that into list. before converting to JSON i can do `response.jsonPath().getList("company");`  to get the values

Comment: `How can i extract that JSON using JAVA?` do you means convert in some java class or else ?

Comment: i want to extract the element and take the values and compare that

Comment: Could you add an example of your JSON?

Answer (score 0):

To extract the element from JSON string you can use Google's [Gson](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/package-summary.html) Library

Example:

```
JSONObject object = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(jsonString);
Set<String> keySet = object.keySet();
for (String key : keySet) {
    Object value = object.get(key);
    System.out.printf("%s=%s (%s)\n", key, value, value.getClass().getSimpleName());
}
```